# How to Bypass the Inconsistent DatePicker Widget in ICS and Jellybean

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-widget, datepicker

I am using Datepicker in Android. I get a tottaly Bizzare UI in Jellybean.

[image]

Here is the Layout Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/stores"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_sales_store"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/products"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_sales_product"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/quantities"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_sales_quantity"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Price"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_sales_price"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="------"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="No of Items"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_sales_num"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6a"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Order Date"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6b"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" >
        <android.widget.DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/dpicker_sales_Order_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow> 

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow7a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Issue Date"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </TableRow> 

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow7b"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"  >  
        <android.widget.DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/dpicker_sales_Issue_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />
    </TableRow> 

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_sales_save"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle_menu"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"        
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:onClick="saveClicked_Sales" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Have you experienced any such Issues?
Is there any way to show just the UI as in GingerBread?

There is no code in the Activity. Just the xml codings.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, consider sending a post to android-developers group where someone from Google might catch up with this issue. Only workaround I can think of would be changing ``android:layout_width="wrap_content"`` for DatePickers.

Comment: @harism  I posted in the group. I used android:layout_width="wrap_content" but nouse. The Issue still Exists.

Comment: Ok, hope you get some help on this issue which looks like a JB bug to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `android:calendarViewShown="false"` to your `<DatePicker>` element to suppress the calendar, if you do not wish to make room for it.

Comment: Thank you sir. Got the Problem Fixed. But this property is not shown in the dropdown suggestions.

Comment: @AndroidKid: By "dropdown suggestions", do you mean Properties pane in Eclipse?

Comment: Nope. I refer to the ctlr+space popup menu in xml layout page

Comment: @AndroidKid: Hmmmm... I've never tried Ctrl-Space in Eclipse before, so I don't know what that does. Regardless, if most Android attributes show up, but this one does not, it may be one the IDE folk forgot, in which case you might file a tools bug report at http://b.android.com.

Comment: Thanks... finally solved a bug that I had on my unresolved list for the last 3 months... :)